# prove that a list returned from a recursively defined function is fixed length in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

How do I prove a lemma like the following:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Lemma len_seq_n : forall start n, length (seq start n)=n.
```

I tried

```
Proof.
induction n.
simpl. auto. simpl.
```

and at this point Coq gives me

```
1 subgoal
start, n : nat
IHn : length (seq start n) = n
______________________________________(1/1)
S (length (seq (S start) n)) = S n
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your induction hypothesis is not general enough.  You need the following statement instead:

```
IHn : forall start', length (seq start' n) = n
```

To obtain this hypothesis, simply generalize over `start` before doing induction on `n` with the `revert` tactic.

```
Proof.
  intros start n.
  revert start.
  induction n.
  (* Continue as previously *)
```

(Next time, please provide a complete example so that we can help you better.  Your question was missing the definition of `seq`.)

Comment: IMVHO a slightly better style would be to reverse the declaration order of the parameters, this way you save the revert.

Comment: And there is the `Lemma seq_length : forall len start, length (seq start len) = len.` there. So, indeed, they stated it as ejgallego suggested.